# C system calls fails

Tags: c, io, system-calls, execvp

I'm trying to write a code which manipulates standard input and output and redirect them to files, and then use execvp (also tried other exec's) to run a program that simply uses printf and scanf , but the execvp fails..

Relevant code:

```
    int pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0) {
        int fdInput = open("myinputfile", O_RDONLY);
        close(0);
        dup(fdInput);
        int fdOutput = open("results.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
        close(1);
        dup(fdOutput);
        char* tmp[]={"...somepath/prog"};
        execvp("...somepath/prog", tmp);
    }
```

My prog:

```
int main(){
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Hello World! %d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

myinputfile contains only -> 4

I tried two main things:

- copying the code from prog and hardcoding it into my code instead of the call to execvp, which works fine and I can see "Hello world! 4" in results.txt
- running "mypath" in the terminal manually which also seems to work(with the standard I/O).

I can't understand why it's not working, I tried everything I could think of..

Comment: `char* tmp[]={"...somepath/prog"};` Is that your actual code? I'm assuming not. Can you please show actual code that you have compiled and run. "But the execvp fails". What does that mean exactly? Did the `execvp` return error.  If so, what was the `errno`?

Comment: Since you are asking about system calls, what system are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array of arguments passed to `execvp()` is not `NULL`-terminated.

Per [the POSIX `exec()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html):

> ...
>
> The argument `argv` is an array of character pointers to null-terminated strings. **The application shall ensure that the last member of this array is a null pointer.** These strings shall constitute the argument list available to the new process image. The value in `argv[0]` should point to a filename string that is associated with the process being started by one of the exec functions.
>
> ...

Your code should be

```
int pid2 = fork();
if (pid2 == 0) {
    int fdInput = open("myinputfile", O_RDONLY);
    close(0);
    dup(fdInput);
    int fdOutput = open("results.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
    close(1);
    dup(fdOutput);

    // note the NULL terminator
    char* tmp[]={"...somepath/prog", NULL };
    execvp("...somepath/prog", tmp);
}
```